Tool use/Function calling using Langchain, AWS Bedrock and Anthropic does not return output
I am trying to get Langchain Bedrock and Anthropic to use a tool/function I have defined in my python file. It does kick off the right tool use and seems to be returning  output_tokens count but no output.
My first query does kick off the right tool called get_weather. But returns no output.
My second query does not kick off any tool usage correctly, as expected, and returns answer.
Code:
import os                                                   # Access to env varibales
from dotenv import find_dotenv, load_dotenv                 # Set up to read API keys from .env #install python-dotenv
dotenv_path = find_dotenv()                                 # find_dotenv wil find teh .env up te parent path 
load_dotenv(dotenv_path)                                    # now you have access to os.environ[HUGGINGFACEHUB_API_TOKEN]

import json

import boto3
from langchain_community.llms import Bedrock

aws_region = "us-east-1"
model_id = "anthropic.claude-v2:1"
model_id = "anthropic.claude-3-sonnet-20240229-v1:0"
model_id = "anthropic.claude-3-sonnet-20240229-v1:0"


model = boto3.client(service_name="bedrock-runtime",  region_name="us-east-1")

# Define a custom tool
def get_weather(input: str) -> str:
    # Replace this with your actual tool implementation
    return f"The weather in {input} is sunny and sujata."

# Define the tool schema
tool_schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "location": {"type": "string", "description": "The city and state, e.g. San Francisco, CA"}
    },
    "required": ["location"]
}

# Define the tool
tool = [{
    "name": "get_weather",
    "description": "Get the current weather in a given location",
    "input_schema": tool_schema
},]



# Define the tools to use
tools = [
    {"name": "get_weather", "description": "Get the current weather in a given location"},
#    {"name": "get_temperature", "description": "Get the current temperature in a given location"}
]

# Create the request body

def query(prompt):
    body = json.dumps({
        "max_tokens": 256,
        "messages": [{"role": "user", "content": prompt}],
        "anthropic_version": "bedrock-2023-05-31",
        "tools": tool
    })


    # Define the prompt
    response = model.invoke_model(body=body, modelId=model_id)
    
    
    print("------------------------------------")
    print("q: " + prompt)

    # Print the response
    #print(response["body"])
    streaming_body=response["body"]
    # Print the contents of the StreamingBody object
    s= streaming_body.read().decode('utf-8')
    sJson= json.loads(s)
    
    
    #print("a: "+ json.dumps(sJson["content"],indent=4))
    print(json.dumps(sJson,indent=4))#["content"])
    
query("What is the weather like in San Francisco?")
query("What is teh capital of India?")

output:
------------------------------------
q: What is the weather like in San Francisco?
{
    "id": "msg_bdrk_01KCn2u3P2f2WCiQ4yuvkpNL",
    "type": "message",
    "role": "assistant",
    "model": "claude-3-sonnet-20240229",
    "content": [
        {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "Okay, let's get the current weather for San Francisco:"
        },
        {
            "type": "tool_use",
            "id": "toolu_bdrk_01J6xY1kfNA1dVMbkqCpAp3K",
            "name": "get_weather",
            "input": {
                "location": "San Francisco, CA"
            }
        }
    ],
    "stop_reason": "tool_use",
    "stop_sequence": null,
    "usage": {
        "input_tokens": 249,
        "output_tokens": 70
    }
}
------------------------------------
q: What is teh capital of India?
{
    "id": "msg_bdrk_011qdVBM8cAq69Z7w7TnVsMs",
    "type": "message",
    "role": "assistant",
    "model": "claude-3-sonnet-20240229",
    "content": [
        {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "The capital of India is New Delhi."
        }
    ],
    "stop_reason": "end_turn",
    "stop_sequence": null,
    "usage": {
        "input_tokens": 248,
        "output_tokens": 11
    }
}


Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

@furas -- appreciate for your time and comment. I did that but removed all my print's before posting the code to make it clean. That's how I know it is kicking off the right tool.
But I did figure out my knowledge gap and have posted my findings.

I did figure out the issue, rather the gap in my knowledge.
The LLM is indeed kicking off the right tool/function to call. But my assumption that it will call the function itself and get the results was incorrect.

Once the LLM figures out the tool/function to call, it responds with tool calls

one then has to code to look at its response to extract the tool and parameters it has used,

 call the tool oneself in one's code ,

then pass back the tool_result to the LLM

and do this in a loop in one's code until there are no more function/tool calls from LLM, as there could be multiple tools being called in one step after another


This is the same approach for OpenAI function calling, but OpenAI has better binding functions available to make it more automatic than Anthropic.

you should create agent, refer langchain doc: https://js.langchain.com/v0.2/docs/how_to/agent_executor/#run-the-agent


please don't use images of code/text, those are not accessible. Make sure to provide properly formatted code as text.
